# How to get Wine to work with SELinux?

Tags: fedora, selinux, wine

I want to run a `.msi` file on Fedora 17. After installing Wine Windows Program Loader on my Linux machine, it failed to run the file. A check on `/var/log/messages` shows the following line:

> Jan 11 17:32:26 some kernel: [15554.188474] type=1400
>   audit(1357983146.108:13): avc:  denied  { mmap_zero } for  pid=4779
>   comm="wine-preloader"
>   scontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:wine_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
>   tcontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:wine_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
>   tclass=memprotect

An online forum has a suggestion to toggle a switch with:

```
setsebool -P mmap_low_allowed 1
```

I did that but it gave me an error:

> libsepol.scope_copy_callback: entropyd: Duplicate declaration in
>   module: type/attribute entropyd_var_run_t (No such file or directory).
>   libsemanage.semanage_link_sandbox: Link packages failed (No such file
>   or directory). Could not change policy booleans

Next, I try setting SELinux to permissive mode with:

```
setenforce 0
```

After checking that SELinux is on permissive mode, I tried to run the file again, but to no avail. What could be causing this problem? And how do I solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Set the boolean `wine_mmap_zero_ignore` to `1` with the command

```
$ sudo setsebool -P wine_mmap_zero_ignore 1
```

Answer (score 1):

To enable new mode of SELinux you should restart your OS but before change your SELinux policy to permissive or disabled permanently via configuration file.